# Text based Fonts

Tags: php, fonts

I have seen in many websites where they create a text which is based on text characters.

```
            o88     o888o  o8
  oooooooo8 oooo  o888oo o888oo
 888ooooooo  888   888    888
         888 888   888    888
 88oooooo88 o888o o888o    888o
```

How do we created such kind of fonts? I remember seeing something about this using PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some PHP scripts:

https://github.com/hush2/figlet

https://github.com/packaged/figlet

Also there is a Zend Text class for Figlet.